# PHP-CLI not found after building with --enable-cli param

Tags: php, centos7

I installed PHP 5.6.1 from source, and I used this configuration during the configure stage.

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-mysql  --enable-cli
>   --enable-mbstring --enable-exif --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-gd  --enable-session --enable-dom --enable-phpdbg --enable-fpm --enable-ctype --with-vpx-dir --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir

I thought it should have given me an error if something went wrong, but I did `make`, `make installed` and all went OK. PHP works just find along with the other extensions, but I can't seem to find `php-cli` anywhere. I have done

```
php -v
php-cli -v
/usr/local/php/bin/php -v
```

All seem to say `-bash: php: command not found`

the only reference to `cli` I found is a file called `cli.h` found in `/usr/local/php/include/php/sapi/cli`

Is there something wrong with this build?

#### EDIT

[Check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9QbR.png), php is actually telling me where the cli binary is, but when I try to run it, it can't find it.

Comment: You should use only `php`, not `php-cli` (I believe it doesn't even exist!). I think `php`can be accessed by `/bin/php`.

Comment: I have tried that. As it does not work `-bash: /bin/php: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Use a command to find all files named php.

Comment: That won't work also. There no other other php-cli files

Comment: Forget about php-cli, search for php only. PHP comes with CLI enabled by default and compiles to the same file, unless you have the flag `--disable-cgi` (source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php). Try to access it on `/usr/local/php` or try to use something like `find / -name php -mount -type f` to try to find where the php file is.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel OK, I am rebuilding everything from scratch, I will try it again.

Comment: There is no need to. Your goal is to find where is the executable file, then running it. If it is easier for you to rebuild, try to save the output to a file. Then you can check what happened and (possibly) verify where is each file.

Comment: Based on your image, try: `/usr/local/php/bin/php`. You tried twice to run the dir. test this: `/usr/local/php/bin/php -r "echo 'working';";`

Comment: No, Actually your previous command `find / -name php -mount -type f` gave me two paths. (1)`/usr/local/php/bin/php` (2)`/usr/local/src/php-5.6.1/sapi/cli/php` the first one did not work, but the second is working. i.e. `/usr/local/src/php-5.6.1/sapi/cli/php -v` gave me the details I wanted. Do you have any idea, why PHP did not move that file to `/bin/php` ?

Comment: My **theory** is that you are working on the dir `/usr/local/`, with all the files to be installed on the same folder.

Comment: If that is the case, then is there any flag/parameter to specify where the SAPI should go, for example during the `./configure` period?

Comment: You should try to follow the steps on this link: https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/329279/how-to-change-the-default-php-install-directory#post1405963 (it is for php 5.3, but I think you can change it). I'm not a linux expert (I'm more a windows guy, I have to or I won't be able to play some games) but I think this will help.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I am using windows too, I just run linux on a virtualbox. Thanks btw

Comment: Since you are running windows, you might want to check for xampp. It's too easy to use it and install it.

Comment: I used XAMPP and then WAMP befpre, but I was told to switch to Linux about a year ago. And so far I love it. Everything is so easy to install and run. I am asking this question, because I am trying to install every component from source, like php 5.6.1 nginx 1.6.2 mariadb 5.5.40 and so on which is hard to do. Otherwise, It is a lot easier to do it with webtatic or remicollet.

Comment: Installing from source is always prone to errors and troubles. But I'm sure that someone else has done it before and there must be a guide **somewhere**. Sadly, my knowledge doesn't allow me to help completely.

Comment: Now thinking, you could try to set a link on `/usr/bin/` pointing to `/usr/local/src/php-5.6.1/sapi/cli/php`. I know that some programs, when installing, they do like this. You can try it, it's not that hard to make a link.

Comment: Yeah, but I preferred to just copy it to `usr/bin` It works now. I'm not too much fond of symlinks. thanks though